# SQLite-Extensions creating empty entries after Update (data inconsistencies)

Tags: sqlite-net

I have the following classes to store meals with SQLiteExtensions. When I store a **SavedMeal** named **M1** having a List of e.g. 3 **SelectedFoods** (e.g. Chicken, Potatoes and Salad) it is stored in my database successfully - great

```
[Table("SavedMeals")]
public class SavedMeal
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]     // Primary Key already indexed in Table
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Unique]                        // Primary Key combined with ID
    public string Name { get; set; }


    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.CascadeInsert | CascadeOperation.CascadeRead | CascadeOperation.CascadeDelete)]
    public List<FoodSelection> SelectedFoods { get; set; } = new List<FoodSelection>();
}
```

```
[Table("FoodSelections")]
public class FoodSelection : Food
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]     // Primary Key already indexed in Table
    public new int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(SavedMeal))]     // Specify the foreign key
    public int SavedMealId { get; set; }


    public new string Name { get; set; }                
}
```

```
static async Task Init()
{
    if (Database is not null)
    {
        return;
    }

    Database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Constants.DatabasePath, Constants.Flags);

    await Database.CreateTableAsync<FoodSelection>();
    await Database.CreateTableAsync<SavedMeal>();
}
```

```
public static async Task AddMeal(SavedMeal mealItem)
{
    await Init();

    await Database.InsertWithChildrenAsync(mealItem, true);
}
```

```
public static async Task UpdateMeal(SavedMeal mealItem)
{
    await Init();

    await Database.UpdateWithChildrenAsync(mealItem);
}
```

When I use **UpdateWithChildrenAsync(...)** to update **M1** which is now only having a List of **2 SelectedFoods** (e.g. Chicken and Salad), I can still see **Potatoes** in my Database but not referenced anymore by **M1**.

Why is that and is there a good way to prevent that and keep the consistency? I thought these Cascade-Attributes should help keeping the database consistent?